# How to access a specific element using *ngfor in angular 2

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ngfor

I am trying to display each element of my array separately in my browser. However both array elements appear at the same time. 
This is an example of what I see in my browser. [image: BrowserImage]

Is there a way to access a specific element and load that elements data elsewhere in the template or either increment an id to show the next array element through a button.

Here is a sample piece of my code:

```
    <div class='panel-body' *ngIf='case'>

        <div>
            <div id="left-side" *ngFor="let tag of case?.involved; let i = index;">
                <p> ID: <span class="name"> {{tag.id}} </span></p>
            </div>
            <div id="right-side" *ngFor="let tag of case?.involved">
                <p>Causeway: <span class="name"> {{tag.causeway}} </span> </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
```

All suggestions will be helpful! Couldn't find any solutions to my problem yet!

Comment: what do you mean by specific element? is it going to be somehow selected or does it have some sort of special attribute? Im having troubles to understand your question

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Thanks for responding. Basically when I say specific element I would like to display element 0 first on the template then I would like to display element 1 but not all at once.

Comment: Added an answer, Im still not sure if I got your question right :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
<div class='panel-body' *ngIf='case'>
        <div>
           <ng-template ngFor let-tag [ngForOf]="case.involved">
              <div id="left-side">
                <p> ID: <span class="name"> {{tag.id}} </span></p>
               </div>
               <div id="right-side">
                 <p>Causeway: <span class="name"> {{tag.causeway}} </span></p>
              </div>
              <hr>
           </ng-template>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly this wouldn't work for me :( Thanks for your help anyway!